# Do apps that let users "Login with your Instagram account" use the Instagram API?

Tags: api, authentication, instagram, account

All of the authentication features I see for the Instagram API make the user "allow access" to your app by redirecting them.  I have seen several apps that let the user login directly, can someone please enlighten me on how they are doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If the app uses Instagram's authentication, it first redirects to `instagram login` page and you have to enter username/password, and then it will show a page to `allow access`, after this it will redirect to the application.

But some apps directly ask for username/password from their UI, these apps store your password, and use it to authenticate using a automated devices running Instagram, so they can post pictures on your behalf, the reason they do this is cause there is no API for posting pic, the only way apps can post pics is by collecting username/password and then posting pics using automated devices. This is risky, never give your username/password. Doing this is against the terms and condition. Only login if the login screen looks like Instagram login page.